# Javascript Array Push to be Stored Properly

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, loops, for-loop

My Program: Creating a test by using select options and text fields. Text field will be entered each time a question is added for picking amount of points.

I have one Array outside the function, that I want to fill with `scores`.

In my `for loop` I try to test if its being filled by showing the `array` itself on the document, which works properly.

my issue: When i send the data to a php file, and echo back the contents... the `scoreArray` is suddenly empty. I can't figure out why since it displays properly on `HTML` but the info received back from the php file is gone.. like i'm accidentally emptying the array after the for loop which doesn't make sense to me.

```js
var testArray = [];
var scoreArray = [];

function examAdd() {
  var ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (ajaxRequest.readyState == 4) {

      var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById('ajaxDiv');
      var res = ajaxRequest.innerHTML = this.responseText;
      var data = JSON.parse(res);
      alert(this.responseText);


      for (i = 1; i < 21; i++) {
        var theID = document.getElementById("q" + i).value;
        scoreArray.push(theID);
        document.getElementById("exam").innerHTML = "Question Array: " + testArray + " || Scores Array: " + scoreArray;
      }
    }
  }

  var topics = document.getElementById("qTopic").value;
  var keywords = document.getElementById("qKeyword").value;
  var testname = document.getElementById("eName").value;


  var myObj = {
    id: "addt",
    test: testArray,
    scores: scoreArray,
    topic: topics,
    keyword: keywords,
    tname: testname
  };
  var myJSON = JSON.stringify(myObj);
  var myJSON2 = JSON.stringify(scoreArray);
  ajaxRequest.open("POST", "examtest.php", true);
  //ajaxRequest.open("POST","https://web.njit.edu/~rtw3/CS490/betamiddle.php", true);
  ajaxRequest.send(myJSON);
}
```

```html
<div id="testLayout">

  <h4>Test</h4>
  <center>
    <ol id="test">
    </ol>
  </center>

</div>

<input type="text" name="eName" id="eName" placeholder="Enter Test Name"><br><br>
<div class="button">
  <input type="button" value="Create" onclick="examAdd();">
  <input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="cancel();">
</div>
```

Comment: If you POST the data to a server what recreates the `scoreArray` when the page response first loads? What persists the data on the server with each Ajax request in `examAdd`? You don't have a url for the request that should make.

Comment: What happens when you post request, does your page reloads, did you console logged any of the variables? I suggest you console log `scoreArray` during the execution of the for loop, before posting it and after.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is the workflow that you show with this code:

1. User enters test name and presses [Create] --> runs `examAdd()`
2. `examAdd()` creates an XML Object and sets a `readystate` handler
3. `examAdd()` creates three vars holding values for `topics,keywords,testname`
4. `examAdd()` creates and `stringifies` and Object literal `myObj`
5. `examAdd()` opens the XHR request
6. `examAdd()` sends the data
7. `examAdd()` receives the and parses the data at `readystate 4`
8. `examAdd()` runs a for loop that pushes a value of an `HTMLInputElement` into `scoreArray`

If this is your intent, the `scoreArray` can only be empty under a few conditions. The suspect here is that the elements with ids of `q1` through `q20` don't exist on the DOM, or if they do they are not `HTMLInputElement`s and they don't have a `value` property.

To test this, console log the value of `theID` in the loop to verify.